# get all values from php associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array `$ages = array("Peter"=>32, "Quagmire"=>30, "Joe"=>34);`. How can i get (echo) all names and corresponding ages in a single instance (like `foreach $value as $value`)?? The array may have more data than shown here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach ($ages as $name => $age) {
echo "$name = $age\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

u have a lot options

like

[print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

```
print_r($array)
```

[var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) , [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
print_r($array);
```

or

```
var_dump($array)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($ages as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . "'s age is " . $value . "<br />";
}
```